# Oracle left join not working as expected

Tags: oracle, left-join

I'm having a problem with a left join. I have tow tables: Customers and WeeklyShop with each customer's weekly summary

I want to select all customers that did not buy in certain period of time.

**My code**

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMER_ID
FROM CUSTOMER c
    left join (
                SELECT distinct(w.CUSTOMER) as id
                FROM WEEKLYSHOP w
                WHERE w.WEEK_START >= beginDate
                    and w.WEEK_END <= endDate
              ) a
    on c.CUSTOMER_ID = a.id
WHERE a.id = null
```

I was expecting this to exclude all the customers in the subquery, leaving me with the ones I need, but it's returning nothing.
If I run only the subquery, it returns the customers with data in that period correctly.

I hope I made myself clear, if there's something needed to add just tell me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `IS NULL` instead of `=` operator to check if a value is not set:

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMER_ID
FROM CUSTOMER c
    left join (
                SELECT distinct(w.CUSTOMER) as id
                FROM WEEKLYSHOP w
                WHERE w.WEEK_START >= beginDate
                    and w.WEEK_END <= endDate
              ) a
    on c.CUSTOMER_ID = a.id
WHERE a.id IS null;
```

Example of NULL in PL/SQL context:

```
DECLARE
 v_bool BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  v_bool := 1 = NULL;

  IF NOT v_bool THEN -- same as IF v_bool = false THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('False.');
  ELSIF v_bool IS NULL THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('NULL.');
  END IF;

  IF (NOT v_bool) IS NULL THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('NOT v_bool is also NULL when v_bool is NULL.');
  END IF;
END;
```

The output:

```
NULL.
NOT v_bool is also NULL when v_bool is NULL.
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it was that. Just to know, what's the difference between both ways?

Comment: @MalincyMontoya you just shouldn't use `=` operator to check if something `IS NULL`, because **it will always return NULL**, and `NULL` in SQL context means `FALSE`. If a value is not set (it is a `NULL`), you can't say if it is equal to something, or not, so you always get `NULL` result. This is important to notice the difference when you are in PL/SQL context - you don't get `FALSE`, but a `NULL` result - check my answer, I've provided an example.